# Java, android - help me understand code please

Tags: java, android

first, I spend all day finding the answers by myself, with no luck.

So, I am learning to develop for Android. I setup SDK, got everything running. I am also new to java and OOP itself. I have benn programming before, I know several Assemblers and C very well.

So, what I dont really understand is, in every game tutorial, game loop and SurfaceView is started like a new thread. But why? Why to start new thread for this, instead just let it flow from activity start method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article on [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) explains this very well.

Comment: In fact, there's a load of invaluable stuff on that site, http://developer.android.com. It's well worth working through it all

Comment: One way to think about multiple threads is as if they were clerks in a store. You don't want the clerk who waits on customers (the UI thread) to also be responsible for keeping the merchandise organized (the game loop). Otherwise, customers will end up waiting for service while the shelves get restocked (the UI will stall), and the customers will go to another store (they'll quit your app in frustration).

Comment: I actually didnt think of input, I thought its asynchronous. You know, in game loop, look if there is any input, if so process it. You dont need to write to screen when you dont know what.

Comment: The point is this: if the game loop is executing on the UI thread, then how is any input going to arrive asynchronously (or at all)? After all, the UI thread is responsible for delivering the user's events (among other things) to the application's event queue. If the game loop is running in the UI thread, you basically have a nested loop structure, where the inner loop is waiting for the outer loop to do something; however the outer loop is stuck waiting for the inner loop to finish.